# Views for XML with attributes using XMlTable

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, xml

I created an XMLType table

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON OF XMLType
  XMLTYPE store AS OBJECT RELATIONAL
  XMLSCHEMA "PERSON.XSD" ELEMENT "root";
```

The XML is -

```
<root>
<Person empid="1" empname="Joe" empproj="IT" emporg="Consulting" />
</root>
```

I created view for the XMLType table. But I could not see the values inserted in table in the view. I want to have the XML attributes (empid, empname, empproj, emporg) as columns of VIEW person_master_view for table PERSON.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
  person_master_view(empid, empname, empproj, emporg)
AS SELECT xt.*
     FROM PERSON,
                XMLTable ('/root/Person' passing PERSON.object_value
                                 columns
                                     empid        number(10)   path '/Person',
                                     empname      varchar2(30) path '/Person',
                                     empproj      varchar2(30) path '/Person',
                                     emporg       varchar2(30) path '/Person'
                             ) as xt
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
      person_master_view(empid, empname, empproj, emporg)
    AS SELECT xt.*
         FROM PERSON P,
                    XMLTable ('//Person' passing P.object_value
                                     columns
                                         empid        number(10)   path '@empid',
                                         empname      varchar2(30) path '@empname',
                                         empproj      varchar2(30) path '@empproj',
                                         emporg       varchar2(30) path '@emporg'
                                 ) as xt
```